# Ultrasonic sensor stops working and blocks code

Tags: python

I am using 4 SRF05 Ultrasonic sensors for my project that operate sequentially. I use Raspberry Pi so the code I am using is the following:

```
def SONAR(TRIG,ECHO):
    GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
        pulse_start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
        pulse_end = time.time()
    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
    distance = pulse_duration*17150
    distance = round(distance, 2)
```

The project also involes 2 more IR sensors and 2 motors. The code works pretty fine but there are many times that The Ultrasound sensors just stop working because of an error I guess, and it is like the code crashing because of an error. Everything stops working apart from the motors that they still run in the last direction they were told to. It is like the program freezes and only the motors rotate and I need to restart the code to resolve it. However, no errors come up on the screen and the program does not stop, otherwise the motors would stop as well. This problem is only caused because of the Ultrasounds. I have tried them separately without anything else running and same thing happens sometimes. Any ideas why this can be happening and how to resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: I think one of your loops keeps looping. If that is so, use some reasonable timeout, for example the time that corresponds to the maximum range of the sonar (should be 0.1s or less).

Comment: I am afraid this is not the case.. the specific sensors need 50ms between every burst. So having 4 of these firing sequentially the 0.05 seconds i use for the sensor to sleep is more than enough. This can happen at any time no matter the distance I am measuring.

Comment: I meant that if a sensor gets stuck (loose cable, happened to me), the loop will always read the same value.

Comment: All of my connections are correct. I think there is some issue with the sensors because they work and after some point they stop and th whole program freezes

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar. What i found was that The Ultrasonic sensors have some problems but they aren't the only problems.

Your while loop must have a time out, other wise it would get stuck. Something like this

```
start = time.time()
count=time.time()
GPIO.setup(sonar,GPIO.IN)
while GPIO.input(sonar)==0 and time.time()-count<0.1:
        start = time.time()
    count=time.time()
    stop=count
    while GPIO.input(sonar)==1 and time.time()-count<0.1:
        stop = time.time()
    # Calculate pulse length
elapsed = stop-start
```

I know this wont solve the problem, as when the Sensor is stuck or not giving a reading, a false reading would be given. I.E the ECHO pin wont be timed correctly.

Look at the pigpio library https://github.com/the-raspberry-pi-guy/robot/blob/master/pi2go/pi2go.py

What i also fond was that an Audrino (or any other Microcontroller) would be better suited for the job of continuously monitoring the Sensors. Raspberry Pi is running Linux and can initiate a system based process.

Also add some delays in your program. This isn't simulation so everything cannot go according to plan.